# Python | How to test for human for a Command Line Interface (CLI)

Tags: python, captcha, command-line-interface

I am writing a python CLI -- and for certain cases I want to test that the user is a human.  Basically implementing a Captcha for a CLI.

It should not depend on remote service

Does anyone have an elegant solution?

Comment: Instead of testing for humans, can't you just have the human or machine self-identify? eg: `mycommand --human=true` or `mycommand --human=false`?

Comment: I think he wants to test whether he is facing a human or a bot on the other end, simmilar to how a Captch works... with your solution, any bot could fake being a human.

Comment: What's to stop the person with access to the CLI from making a copy of your Python script editing out the "captcha" and running that? Generally speaking someone who has access to a CLI (ie. a shell) in order to run a Python script also has full access to everything that the script does and so can write an equivalent script.

Comment: Yeah nothing.  And I am aware of that.  I should eloborate the problem statement.

People get desensitized to prompts in CLI:  They just press 'Y' to move the script along.  Before a potentially hazardous operation I really want to the user to think for a second before moving on

Comment: Having them type "yes" is the usual solution to that specific problem. Another is to have them type the name (again) of what they want to delete or destroy. More generally having them answer a simple math question should do the trick, but it won't necessarily be accepted by your users.

Answer (score 3):

What about ASCII art? And a question along the line: Who or what is displayed on this image?

See [https://www.google.de/search?q=ascii+art](https://www.google.de/search?q=ascii%20art)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a set of questions in your script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
# encoding: utf-8

import sys
import time
import random
import hashlib

def ask_question():
  questions = [
    ('What animal has a trunk?', ('1c6f116ce35bbe8b5c5b3a26cfa9e63c4b7cff24', '0ae9e4deba26021986ffd99636da6601f6393631')),
    ('How many continents are there?', ('902ba3cda1883801594b6e1b452790cc53948fda')),
    ('Where is Big Ben?', ('707fe00aa123eb0be5010f1d3065c2b6d7934ca4', '4c57f0c88d9844630327623633ce269cf826ab99'))
  ]
  random.seed(time.time())
  question = questions[random.randint(0, len(questions) - 1)]
  answers = question[1]
  question = question[0]
  sys.stdout.write(question + '\n')
  try:
    user = input('Answer: ')
  except NameError:
    user = raw_input('Answer: ')
  sha1 = hashlib.new('sha1')
  sha1.update(user.encode())
  if sha1.hexdigest() not in answers:
    sys.stderr.write('Not a correct answer\n')
    sys.exit(1)

ask_question()
```

To be used like:

```
[matt tests] ./questions.py 
What animal has a trunk?
Answer: Elephant
[matt tests] ./questions.py 
What animal has a trunk?
Answer: Wolf
Not a correct answer
[matt tests]
```

The SHA1 is so the user cannot parse the answers by loading the script. Ideally you would add a salt to each of the hashes to protect against brute force but that'd be overkill as you could always just modify the python code.

Answer (score 0):

I had an idea to use the [pyfiglet](https://github.com/pwaller/pyfiglet) module to solve this. Figure it is easy to pass as a human, and easy to add the check to your Python, but hard to automate parsing the output with a script.

```py
# File: captch.py

import pyfiglet
import random
import sys


def main():
    check_number = random.randint(0, 9999)
    check_string = f"{check_number:>04}"
    print(pyfiglet.Figlet().renderText(check_string))
    response = input("Please enter the number shown above to proceed: ")
    if response != check_string:
        print("Failed verification check!", file=sys.stderr)
        exit(-1)
    print("Passed verification check!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

A passing verification example using the code above:

```sh
$ python captcha.py 
 _____ _  _  _____ ___  
|___ /| || ||___ // _ \ 
  |_ \| || |_ |_ \ (_) |
 ___) |__   _|__) \__, |
|____/   |_||____/  /_/ 
                        

Please enter the number shown above to proceed: 3439
Passed verification check!
```

A failing verification example using the code above:

```sh
$ python captcha.py 
 ____ _____ ___ _____ 
|___ \___  / _ \___ / 
  __) | / / | | ||_ \ 
 / __/ / /| |_| |__) |
|_____/_/  \___/____/ 
                      

Please enter the number shown above to proceed: 1234
Failed verification check!
```